# SQL PHP group by multiple columns

Tags: php, sql

I want to get the output from following table

```
Code     Name 
100      A
100      B
200      C
300      D
300      E
300      F
```

I want the output as

```
Code     Name 
100      A
         B
200      C
300      D
         E
         F
```

How can I get like this?

Comment: formatting like this should be done in application layer.

Comment: Basically, you just select * from blaa where Code=100 and then "sort by name", if needed. In any case, you would format the "output" with your PHP/HTML/CSS code. Nothing is forcing you to show the value of "Code" for each field you got from SQL.

Comment: You can do it in php easily

Comment: can you please tell me how  Zain Farooq?pleaseee

Comment: Please, could you post your code that made the query and display the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `php` and `sql` for this purpose. You should first use this query to get all names separately through `php`.

```
select distinct(name) as name from table_name
```

Store result of this query in php variable in while loop and run a sql query again in loop

```
select code from table_name where name='$php_name_variable'
```

In this way you can get your desired output.